# BackUp, архивация документов исключения, zip

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zip

У меня есть простой скрипт

```
  7z a -tzip -v5g -y -ssw -x!*.avi -x!*.mp3 -x!*.mpg4    /media/hdd/backup/full_archive.zip '/media/serv1/'
```

`'/media/serv1/'` это источник (откуда создается архив)

`media/hdd/backup/full_archive.zip` это путь и архив (куда создается архив `zip`)

`-x!*.avi -x!*.mp3 -x!*.mpg4` это исключения

В папке так же есть файлы `~$*.docx` ( например, `~$document.docx` )

Подобные обозначения не прокатывает

```
-x!'~$'* 
-x!'~$*.docs'
```

Как обозначить подобное исключения ?

И так же как сделать так чтобы после полного бакапа, можно было сделать дифференцированный бакап (то есть создавались архивы только с измененными файлами в отдельном файле архиве `zip` )